# Getting integer values from intent in android(eclipse)

Tags: android, android-intent

This is my first activity and from here I want to take the value from the EditBox,  which has an integer value in it.

```
final EditText playerNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playerNum);
Intent intent = new Intent(InitialActivity.this, TapMe.class);
intent.putExtra("MyString", playerNum.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

This is my second activity, where I want the integer value from the previous intent.

```
final TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
int iterations = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("MyString"));
```

This should have worked, but unfortunately, it isn't. Not able to figure out why??

Comment: `getIntent().getString("MyString")`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
int iterations = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("MyString"));
```

This will definitely solve your problem.

Important note:

We use this syntax : `getIntent().getExtras().getString("MyString")` when we are sending data using `Bundle`. But here in your case you are sending data in your Intent only. So you need to use the syntax that I mentioned above.

**EDIT:**

If the above approach is not working then try checking it with Bundle class.

Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(InitialActivity.this, TapMe.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("MyString", playerNum.getText().toString());
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your Second activity you can receive your data by:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int iterations = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("MyString"));
```

Comment: I did that but now it's getting "unfortunately stopped". Not going on to my second intent as well.

Comment: iterations = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("MyString"));
  score.setText("iterations"+iterations);

Comment: @ShreyashMehta : updated my answer.. you can try it and if error still persists then please send your stack trace